# Typescript .push'ing data from a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am having issues returning (pushing) data from a nest array. The JSON object I have is as follows:

```
{
  component: Assembly,
  title: "Assembly",
  path: "/assembly",
  sections: {
      title: "Frame Assembly",
      steps: {
      ["Step 1"]: {
         content:"step 1 content"
      },
      ["Step 2"]: {
        content: "step 2 content"
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I am using this data to build a navigation of sorts. This is my function to do this.

```
private BuildNavigation = (navItem: any) => {

const subSections = [];
const sections = navItem.sections;
  for (const key in sections) {
    if (sections.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      subSections.push(
        <>
          <ul>
            <li key={key}><ScrollLink to={`${currentPath}#${key}`.toLowerCase()}>{sections[key].title}</ScrollLink></li>
            {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sections[key].steps).forEach((step: string) => {
                // How do I return step
                console.log(step);
              })}
          </ul>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
return subSections;
}
```

I can log out `step` fine and get the correct info but I cannot get it to return (push) into `subSections`.

I am hoping for some output similar to:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="/assembly">Assembly</a>
      <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">
         <li><a href="/assembly#frameassembly">Frame Assembly</a></li>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="/assembly#frameassembly-step-1">Step 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/assembly#frameassembly-step-2">Step 2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: How do you want to have those steps represented? At that spot you already closed the `li` tag. You want each step to be output in other `li` elements?

Comment: @trincot added expected output. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is reactjs, in which case it would be useful to add the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line:

```
        <li key={key}><ScrollLink to={`${currentPath}#${key}`.toLowerCase()}>{sections[key].title}</ScrollLink></li>
```

You can continue as follows:

```
        <ul>
           {
              Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sections[key].steps).map((step: string) => {
                 return (<li>{step}</li>);
              })
           }
        </ul>
```